# How to risize VirtualBox dynamic disk for Debian guest (windows 10 host)

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, partitioning, debian, virtual-machine

I created a debian virtual machine with current version (5.2.2 r119230) of virtual box. I set up a dynamic disk with 20GB maximum. Current size as stated by VirtualBox is 8.31GB.

The problem is that the guest system (debian 9) tells me that there is nearly no space left (11.9GB of 12GB used).

So how to tell Debian that it could use up to 20GB? Or is there any way to give Debian more space its primary disk?